# Unwanted Button Styling on IMG

Tags: html, css, menu

I'd like to start by saying sorry because I know this is probably going to be a very easy fix or something obvious I'm missing like you can't use an IMG as a button.

[image: This is supposed to be just a white hamburger image]

As you can see theres a white border that wont go away. It's supposed to just be a white hamburger image.

What am I missing here?

The HTML:

```
<div class="mini-nav-menu">
    <button><img src="assets/menu.png"/></button>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.mini-nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}

.mini-nav-menu img {
     width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Please send the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify or add some CSS property on your button html tag. 
Please add a class to button. (Lets name as **btn-class**)

your **HTML**

```
<div class="mini-nav-menu">
    <button class="btn-class"><img src="assets/menu.png"/></button>
</div>
```

and Add **CSS** for the button class :

```
.btn-class {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
background: transparent;
border: 0;
outline: 0; // optional
```

This should help you.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, knew it was something simple I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

make button look like a link:

```
button {
 background:none!important;
 color:inherit;
 border:none; 
 padding:0!important;
 font: inherit;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: All that was needed was background: transparent; and border: 0;
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @FreddieErgatoudis for better browser support I'd recommend "background:none"

Answer (score 0):

**May be it will work try this :**

```
.mini-nav-menu button {
     background:transparent;
     border:none;
     outline:none;
}
```